# Python 3 - Program that requests positive integer and prints first 4 multiples of it

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, input, casting

I'm working on a problem that involves putting in an input, integer n, that when doing so will print off the following 4 "multiples" of the integer. I need to do this for 3 integers, n = 5, n = 0, n = 3.

Original Question:

> Implement a program that requests a positive
>   integer n from the user and prints the first four multiples of n: Test
>   your module for  n = 5; n = 0 and n = 3.

The output of the code should look like:

```
>>>
   Enter n: 5
   5
   10
   15
   20
```

So, what I've come up with so far is this

```
n = (input("Enter n:"))
```

This allows me to input an integer value.

Next using `print(n)`, this will print the value I input (Ex. number 5), but I'm not sure how to print off multiples of it after. I realize it's a loop question, most likely involving `if` or `in`, but I'm not sure where to go after this.

Answer (score 0):

You've pretty much figured out the question on your own. The correct code is:

```
n = int(input("Enter n:"))
for i in range(4):
    print(n*(i+1))
```

So, what this for loop does for you is repeat your print statement 4 times, where you give `i` the values of the expression `range(4)`.

If you just `print(range(4))`, you'll see that it evaluates to `[0,1,2,3]`. That's why I had to add 1 to it each time.

The `int()` function call is needed because `input()` returns a string, not a number. So if we want the mathematical operators to do what we expect, we need to first convert it to a number (in this case, an integer).

Comment: Missing  an `int()` maybe?

Comment: I was missing one! That's embarrassing. That'll teach me to test before I post.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. So, now I understand that you need to designate the input  with the int() function as well if you're looking for integers/numbers, but its not required when working words/strings. Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general logic:

```
n = (input("enter n:"))
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++){
    print(int(float((n))*i);
}
```

Comment: This has the advantage of accepting non-integer numbers as input, but it truncates them without rounding. Printing a newline is not necessary, as print() automatically adds one for you. You'll end up with an extra line in between each numbers, which does not match the output given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the list to start with 0 you can do this, it has an error but it can be fixed...

```
number = int(input("Give a number:"))
for multiples in range(10):
    getal1 = number * multiples
    print("\t The", str(multiples + 1) + "e multiple of," + number, "is", str(getal1) + ".")
```